# Feathersjs auto increment on hook

Tags: hook, feathersjs

Is there a simpler way to perform auto increment for the GET api with the use of hook? Trying to implement something like view count, where it auto increment the count after a GET.

```
const portfoliosHooks = {
  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
const portfoliosHooks = {
  after: {
    all: [],
    find: [],
    get: [
      hook => hook.service.patch(hook.id, { views: hook.result.views + 1 })
    ],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
}
```

hook.service is the service the hook is running on. This assumes you have a POJO result. If not, you'd have to flatten it first (`toObject()` or `toJSON()` depending on your db).

Comment: Great! It works except that I need to use hook.result.id instead of hook.id.